# Access properties of unknown type in IList<T>

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, reflection

I am implementing a custom control, which receives a list of properties in type T (as strings) and an IList and renders it in to an HTML table. I have the markup and `CreateChildControls` part down.

What I want to do is go through the properties via reflection and get the values for the properties inside a `foreach` loop running on the List.

I don't know what T is at compile time, and I want to be able to accommodate List for any T.

What would be the best way to do this?

**EDIT:**

```
public class CustomControl : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl, INamingContainer
{
    private List<string> _properties;
    private **?????????** _dataSource;

    public List<string> Properties
    { set { _properties = value; } }

    public **?????????** DataSource
    { set { _dataSource = value; } }
}
```

Now lets say I set the value of Properties to something like this:

```
_properties = new List<string>()
        {
            "FirstName",
            "LastName"
        };
```

And pass in a list of object of type person:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName
    { get; set; }
    public string LastName
    { get; set; }
}
```

The person calss is just a place holder. I would like to do this for any T in List.
The calling class knows the type T and the custom control does not. Also, the custom control itself is not planned to be a generic class.
Hope this helps focus my question.

Comment: Well, what have you tried? (Hint: `typeof(T).GetProperty(...)` is your friend...)

Comment: @JonSkeet - What type should the property for the List<T> be? IList? Do I need to cast it? If so, to what?

Comment: I don't know - we don't know enough about the context. (Can this be a generic method, for example? Or a generic type? Does the caller know the type, or should it be dynamic?)

Comment: @JonSkeet - I updated my question with code samples and a better explenation (I hope :)) Thank you!

Comment: `foreach (var x in _dataSource) { x.GetType().GetProperty(...) }` is not what you looking for?

Comment: @IliaG - var needs to be known at compile time, and it will not be...

Comment: @EladLachmi var is going to be inferred to what the item type of the _datasource is, so if you declare it as `List<int>` it will be int, and if you declare it as `List<object>` it will be object. It works perfectly fine for generic types.

Comment: @IliaG - But _dataSource is IEnumerable. How can the compiler know when I don't even know at compile time?

Comment: `var` will simply compile as `object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your datasource as a plain `IEnumerable`, and then get the values for each type with reflection. For example:

```
private IEnumerable _dataSource;

foreach (object o in _dataSource)
{
    foreach (string propName in _properties)
    {
        PropertyInfo prop = o.GetType().GetProperty(propName);

        // ...
    }
}
```